# Where can I run a mysql command line under Azure to fix "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version (1148)"

Tags: mysql, azure

I have a MySQL database which is hosted in Azure, and I have MySQL Workbench installed on my laptop. I want to do some importing from a CSV file located in my laptop, but whenever I try to that, I get an error message saying:

> The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version

I did some online searching, and I found out that I need to run the following command:

```
mysql -u myuser -p --local-infile somedatabase
```

But, I don't know where I have to run it, and how, while as I said my database is hosted in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql` is just the commandline executable of the MySql client. And most probably it is even part of the MySql workbech - just check the MySQL Workbech working folder. But the result will not be different is my guess.

The best way you can manage Import/Export for MySQL is to use a [Free Tier WebSite](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/websites/) and Install the [phpMyAdmin extension](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/phpmyadmin/).